# Cannot install net-snmp because of failed dependency

Tags: linux, installation, rpm, suse

I have a server here that is running SuSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (i586) patch level 1.  I am trying to install Net-SNMP on the machine.  I downloaded the net-snmp-5.4.2.1-8.2.i586.rpm file and tried to install it:

```
ourserver1:~ # rpm -i net-snmp-5.4.2.1-8.2.i586.rpm
warning: net-snmp-5.4.2.1-8.2.i586.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 034e6912
error: Failed dependencies:
        perl-SNMP = 5.4.2.1 is needed by net-snmp-5.4.2.1-8.2.i586
```

So then I downloaded perl-SNMP-5.4.2.1-8.2.i586.rpm and tried to install it:

```
ourserver1:~ # rpm -i perl-SNMP-5.4.2.1-8.2.i586.rpm
warning: perl-SNMP-5.4.2.1-8.2.i586.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 034e6912
error: Failed dependencies:
        net-snmp = 5.4.2.1 is needed by perl-SNMP-5.4.2.1-8.2.i586
```

Why does each one depend on the other?  How do I get Net-SNMP installed on this machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install both at the same time.

```
rpm -Uvh net-snmp-5.4.2.1-8.2.i586.rpm perl-SNMP-5.4.2.1-8.2.i586.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. MY OS was: SLES-11 SP3 and i want to install net-snmp. This command resolves the dependency errors.

## rpm -Uvh net-snmp-5.4.2.1-8.12.16.1.x86_64.rpm perl-SNMP-5.4.2.1-8.12.16.1.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Yes, and it is exactly the same solution which was originally accepted already two years ago, except that yours has different version numbers. Please do read the already provided solutions before posting a new one.